# Use an image in Wagtail's Base.html template

Tags: django, python-3.x, wagtail

I'm looking to add a logo to my base.html by pulling from the page model...  But I don't have access to the base.html page model through wagtail, and so I don't know where to create a ImageChooserPanel to specify the logo for my navbar (which should be applied to all pages).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your models.py file add a [setting](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/reference/contrib/settings.html#defining-settings):

```
from django.db import models
from wagtail.contrib.settings.models import BaseSetting, register_setting
from wagtail.images.models import Image
from wagtail.images.edit_handlers import ImageChooserPanel

@register_setting
class SiteSettings(BaseSetting):
    logo = models.OneToOneField(Image, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='+', verbose_name='Business logo')
    panels = [
        ImageChooserPanel('logo'),
    ]
```

In your admin Settings menu you will now see Site Settings.  Click on that to choose your logo.

In your template at the top:

```
{% load wagtailimages_tags %}
```

And then render with:

```
{% image settings.app_label.SiteSettings.logo width-300 %}
```

where `app_label` is the app/folder where you have your `models.py` file.

Reference:  https://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/reference/contrib/settings.html#using-in-django-templates

Comment: In addition to this I had to add wagtail.contrib.settings to my installed apps.  But now I'm not sure how to access this in my base template.  {% image self.logo original as logo %} is not seeming to work when using <img src="url('{{ logo.url }}')">.  Specifically, the loaded URL is empty.

Comment: See amended answer.

Comment: This is not working in 5.1 as showing error here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77026685/after-upgrade-to-wagtail-5-1-getting-the-error-cannot-pickle-io-bufferedread/77117398#77117398