# After upgrade to Wagtail 5.1, getting the error: cannot pickle '_io.BufferedReader' object

Tags: wagtail

Python 3.8, Wagtail 5.1, Ubuntu 20.04, and pipenv to pin all dependencies

I've successfully upgraded a small site by working through each minor version from Wagtail 4.0 through 5.0.  When I upgrade to 5.1, I'm now getting the above error for an `{% image ... %}` tag in both the admin and the site.  This code worked on version 5.0 with no problem.  Both image references are from a database record.  From the admin template:

```
{% extends "wagtailadmin/base.html" %}
    {% load wagtailimages_tags %}
    
    {% block branding_logo %}
        {% image settings.main.SiteSettings.logo_admin width-150 %}
    {% endblock %}
```

And this is the `{% image ... %}` tag in the home page template:

```
{% image settings.main.SiteSettings.logo_admin height-85 alt="Home" title="Home" style="position:relative; margin-bottom:-4px" %}
```

I suspect that this error has to do with the [Upgrade consideration:  Image renditions are now cached by default](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/latest/releases/5.1.html#image-renditions-are-now-cached-by-default).  This site gets such low traffic that it does not need to have images cached, and so I didn't want to bother setting up a cache.  However, is Wagtail now forcing the use of a cache?  Or is there an error in the Wagtail code?  Is there a way to resolve this error without setting up a cache?

Relevant portion of the Traceback:

```
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1005, in <listcomp>
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 966, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 63, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1005, in render
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1005, in <listcomp>
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 966, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wagtail/images/templatetags/wagtailimages_tags.py", line 129, in render
    rendition = get_rendition_or_not_found(
  File "/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wagtail/images/shortcuts.py", line 13, in get_rendition_or_not_found
    return image.get_rendition(specs)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wagtail/images/models.py", line 455, in get_rendition
    Rendition.cache_backend.set(cache_key, rendition)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/cache/backends/locmem.py", line 53, in set
    pickled = pickle.dumps(value, self.pickle_protocol)

Exception Type: TypeError at /admin/
Exception Value: cannot pickle '_io.BufferedReader' object
```

Comment: I reported this as a bug and it was confirmed as such by a member of the Wagtail team:  https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/10879

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this issue today as well and I did not try with other caching options yet.

But I try this [option](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/latest/advanced_topics/images/image_serve_view.html#dynamic-image-serve-view) and it seems working fine. So just use image_url instead of image tag and add its handle in the project urls.py file:

```
{% image settings.main.SiteSettings.logo_admin "height-85" %}
```

in project urls.py file:

```
re_path(r'^images/([^/]*)/(\d*)/([^/]*)/[^/]*$', ServeView.as_view(), name='wagtailimages_serve'),...
```

Comment: Wagtail 5.1 seems to have fixed this problem.